# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After the last question you get an error   - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')

```
import React from "react";

function Map(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.object.question}</p>

      {props.object.answers.map((e) => (
        <>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={e.id}
            name={props.object.id}
            value={e.correct}
          />
          <label for={e.id}>{e.answer}</label>
          <br />
        </>
      ))}

      <input
        type="submit"
        value="პასუხი"
        onClick={() => props.setRagaca(props.ragaca + 1)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... that error means that props.object is not an object.

1. **If this is not a problem and you want only prevent the error**, i suggest you the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).  In this way, when props.object is null or undefined, the results become undefined with no error (i.e, the html show an empty string)

Usage:

```
props.object?.question // note the question mark before .question
```

2. **If this is a problem**... the bug isn't in this part of code.

*Ps. this is not your question, but replace...*

```
() => props.setRagaca(props.ragaca + 1)
```

with:

```
() => props.setRagaca((x) => x+1) // better way to do the same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the page renders before the states of props gets passed to the component that's why reactjs can't seem to find it it's either null or undefined

you can get rid of this with optional chaining

```
import React from "react";

function Map(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.object.question}</p>

      {props?.object?.answers.map((e) => (
        <>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={e.id}
            name={props.object.id}
            value={e.correct}
          />
          <label for={e.id}>{e.answer}</label>
          <br />
        </>
      ))}

      <input
        type="submit"
        value="პასუხი"
        onClick={() => props.setRagaca(props.ragaca + 1)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

this gives an extra layer of assurance if and only if the object is present then, do this.